# How to make specific "tree view"

Tags: php, jquery, css, treeview

I want to create some sort of tree view, although I don´t know if it´s the correct word. I draw the picture of it for you to understand what I mean. Basically it looks like upside down flower.
[image: supposed tree-like view]

What´s the best way to do this? For every user registered under logged user there should be a new branch with his picture and name and number of branches is not limited. 
I suppose jQuery is the way but I wasn´t able to find anything that could help me. So I would be glad for any links or tips for jQuery plugins or any other useful tips.

Comment: Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions **asking us to recommend or find** a book, tool, **software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: no code no answer

Comment: You can draw it as a table of 7 columns, col1 : user 1 lable, col2: user1 image, col3 : branch connector, col4 :horizontal line and col5 : for user two and so on ..

Comment: Sorry for wrong question...Since I have no idea how to do this, there is no code. I just don´t even know how to start and google search was to no use to me so far. So I tried to ask for help and some basic direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have gone a little overboard with this answer, but it's been fun testing some things out so I made a complete solution. The layout adapts to size changes for most elements. I've tried to make the CSS as easy to edit as possible.

All you need to do is duplicate `level_2_entry_container` as many times as you like. This can be easily accomplished either client-side or server side with a couple lines of code. The content structure is the same for both the left and right side (the direction and positioning is controlled via CSS).

Tested on the latest versions Chrome and Firefox.

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
}
.main_container {
    min-width: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.solution_container {
    position: relative;
}
.flex_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.flex_item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
}
.flex_item_static {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.level_1_entry_image {
    width: 160px; /* change according to preference */
    height: 160px; /* change according to preference */
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 4px #eee;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.level_1_entry_content {
    padding-left: 20px; /* change according to preference - controls text distance from level_1_image */
}
.center_line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 1;
}
.center_footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 4px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 1;
}
.level_2_entry_container {
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
.level_2_entry_container:first-child {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-right: auto;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: auto;
}
.level_2_entry_image,
.level_2_entry_content {
    margin: 20px; /* change according to preference - controls level_2_image distance from central_line */
}
.level_2_entry_image {
    width: 100px; /* change according to preference */
    height: 100px; /* change according to preference */
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 4px #eee;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(odd) .level_2_entry_image {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(even) .level_2_entry_image {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.level_2_entry_content {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding: 20px; /* change according to preference - controls text distance from level_2_image */
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(odd) .level_2_entry_content {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    text-align: right;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(even) .level_2_entry_content {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    text-align: left;
}
.diagonal_line_1,
.diagonal_line_2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
}
.diagonal_line_1 {
    right: 0px;
}
.diagonal_line_2 {
    left: 0px;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(odd) .diagonal_line_2 {
    display: none;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(even) .diagonal_line_1 {
    display: none;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(odd) > .flex_container > .flex_item:nth-child(1) {
    order: 1;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(odd) > .flex_container > .flex_item:nth-child(2) {
    order: 2;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(even) > .flex_container > .flex_item:nth-child(1) {
    order: 2;
}
.level_2_entry_container:nth-child(even) > .flex_container > .flex_item:nth-child(2) {
    order: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main_container">
            <div class="solution_container">
                <div class="flex_container">
                    <div class="flex_item"></div>
                    <div class="flex_item flex_item_static">
                        <img class="level_1_entry_image" src="http://placehold.it/320x320"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex_item">
                        <div class="level_1_entry_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="center_line"></div>
                <div class="center_footer"></div>
                <div class="level_2_container">
                    <div class="level_2_entry_container">
                        <div class="flex_container">
                            <div class="flex_item">
                                <div class="level_2_entry_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_item flex_item_static">
                                <img class="level_2_entry_image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_1">
                                    <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_2">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_2_entry_container">
                        <div class="flex_container">
                            <div class="flex_item">
                                <div class="level_2_entry_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_item flex_item_static">
                                <img class="level_2_entry_image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_1">
                                    <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_2">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_2_entry_container">
                        <div class="flex_container">
                            <div class="flex_item">
                                <div class="level_2_entry_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_item flex_item_static">
                                <img class="level_2_entry_image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_1">
                                    <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_2">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_2_entry_container">
                        <div class="flex_container">
                            <div class="flex_item">
                                <div class="level_2_entry_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_item flex_item_static">
                                <img class="level_2_entry_image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_1">
                                    <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_2">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_2_entry_container">
                        <div class="flex_container">
                            <div class="flex_item">
                                <div class="level_2_entry_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_item flex_item_static">
                                <img class="level_2_entry_image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_1">
                                    <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_2">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_2_entry_container">
                        <div class="flex_container">
                            <div class="flex_item">
                                <div class="level_2_entry_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_item flex_item_static">
                                <img class="level_2_entry_image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_1">
                                    <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_2">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_2_entry_container">
                        <div class="flex_container">
                            <div class="flex_item">
                                <div class="level_2_entry_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_item flex_item_static">
                                <img class="level_2_entry_image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_1">
                                    <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_2">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_2_entry_container">
                        <div class="flex_container">
                            <div class="flex_item">
                                <div class="level_2_entry_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_item flex_item_static">
                                <img class="level_2_entry_image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_1">
                                    <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                                <svg viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="diagonal_line_2">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="0.4" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Very nice, thank you so much! This is exactly what I´ve been looking for. I´ve been trying to make it with table and html5 canvas in the meantime, since I didn´t find any plugin. But the result isn´t the best :) This is much better, thanks! I appreciate your time.

Comment: Now I made it dynamic with PHP, edited it a little and it works like a charm. Once again many thanks :)

Comment: Glad you found it useful :)